# Copying more than two collections from firestore to another collection doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have four collections in my firestore database:

1. EnglishQuestions
2. MathQuestions
3. ScienceQuestions
4. DzongkhaQuestions

I am trying to copy all the data from those collections and put it under one collection for each user. So it would look like this.

1. username(collection)

   - MathQuestions (doc) - Questions (collection)
   - EnglishQuestions (doc) - Questions (collection)
   - ScienceQuestions (doc) - Questions (collection)
   - DzongkhaQuestions (doc) - Questions (collection)
     However, when I am trying to do this, it act weirdly in the sense that sometimes, all the four collections gets copied in the username collection but other times only the first two collections or the first collection gets copied.

Before I had the part where you call the database for each collection one after another. Since that didn't work I tried to make each call a function of its own as seen below. Sadly that doesn't work as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

After taking @ralemos's suggestion, it still doesn't work but the new code looks like the following.

```
    fire
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then((u) => {
        let user = fire.auth().currentUser;
        console.log(user);
        if (user != null) {
          user
            .updateProfile({
              displayName: this.state.name,
            })
            .then((r) => {
              let db = fire.firestore();
              let data = {
                name: this.state.name,
                email: this.state.email,
                college: this.state.college,
                dzongkhag: this.state.dzongkhag,
              };
              db.collection(this.state.email).doc("UserProfile").set(data);
              this.copyMathDatabase();
            });
        }
      });
  }
  copyMathDatabase() {
    let db = fire.firestore();
    db.collection("Questions")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          db.collection(this.state.email).doc("MathQuestions").collection("Questions").doc(doc.id).set({
            Category: doc.data().Category,
            Choice: doc.data().Choice,
            CorrectAnswer: doc.data().CorrectAnswer,
            IsCorrectAnswer: doc.data().IsCorrectAnswer,
            IsWrongAnswer: doc.data().IsWrongAnswer,
            Question: doc.data().Question,
            UserHasNotResponded: doc.data().UserHasNotResponded,
            Marked: doc.data().Marked,
          });
          console.log("Math Questions: ", doc.id);
        });
        this.copyEnglishDatabase();
        console.log(" Done copying the Math database ");
      });
  }

  copyEnglishDatabase() {
    let db = fire.firestore();
    db.collection("EnglishQuestions")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          db.collection(this.state.email).doc("EnglishQuestions").collection("Questions").doc(doc.id).set({
            Category: doc.data().Category,
            Choice: doc.data().Choice,
            CorrectAnswer: doc.data().CorrectAnswer,
            IsCorrectAnswer: doc.data().IsCorrectAnswer,
            IsWrongAnswer: doc.data().IsWrongAnswer,
            Question: doc.data().Question,
            UserHasNotResponded: doc.data().UserHasNotResponded,
            Marked: doc.data().Marked,
            Passage: doc.data().Passage,
            isPassageQuestion: doc.data().isPassageQuestion,
          });
          console.log("English Questions: ", doc.id);
        });
       
        console.log("Done copying the English database");
      });
  }
```

Comment: Your code shows that you are only trying to copy the first two collections at this point:
```js
this.copyMathDatabase();
this.copyEnglishDatabase();
```

Comment: @JayCodist I removed the other two calls since I wanted to just try with two. If i call only one, it works but as soon as I try to copy two collections, it acts weird. It sometimes copies and other times doesnt.

Comment: Since both copy routines are asynchronous, are you checking for their completion (especially the writes) *before* your top-level exists?

Comment: Yes I changed my code so that it now forces the one to complete before the other can start and it still doesn't work. @LeadDreamer

Comment: May we see *how* you changed the code? Rather difficult for us to offer assistance by just guessing...

Comment: @LeadDreamer I edited the code to show the new code.

Comment: Yeah, that still won't work - you need to learn a LOT more about exactly what promises and .then() really mean.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, many/most Firestore calls return a *promise* - which means the result of an operation to be returned later, possibly *much* later.  Just putting one call after the other does NOT mean one will wait for the other - that isn't at all what promises do.  You may have seen some code that uses async/await, which ***LOOK*** like they wait for each other - but it's just "syntactic sugar" (i.e. makes it look good) that hides the fact that there are ***STILL*** promises "behind the scenes".

For *your* example, I would do the following:

```
copyMathDatabase() {
    let db = fire.firestore();
    return db.collection("Questions")
    ...
}

copyEnglishDatabase() {
    let db = fire.firestore();
    return db.collection("EnglishQuestions")
    ...
}
```

Note the "return"  - each function now returns the ***PROMISE*** of a result, which will happen sometime later. Then, in your auth function area:

```
  fire
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then((u) => {
        let user = fire.auth().currentUser;
        console.log(user);
        if (user != null) {
          user
            .updateProfile({
              displayName: this.state.name,
            })
            .then((r) => {
              let db = fire.firestore();
              let data = {
                name: this.state.name,
                email: this.state.email,
                college: this.state.college,
                dzongkhag: this.state.dzongkhag,
              };
              return db.collection(this.state.email).doc("UserProfile").set(data);
            })
            .then(() => {
              return this.copyMathDatabase();
             })
            .then(() => {
              return this.copyEnglishDatabase();
            };
        }
      });
  }
```

note - the result of the .set() returns a ***PROMISE*** to be completed when it is done; .then() waits for that promise *then* executes copyMathDatabase(), which returns a ***PROMISE*** to be completed when it is done; .then() waits for that promise *then* executes copyEnglishDatabase(), which returns a ***PROMISE*** to be completed when it is done.

This question shows you have very very little understanding of exactly what promises are - and that understanding is absolutely critical and necessary to using Firestore.  You need to go and teach yourself promises in detail before you continue.  You should also learn what the aync/await syntax is, and what it *actually* does.  This is NOT the place for you to learn these things.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The method you have given also works partially. Everything works well and all the collections are copied perfectly sometimes. But sometimes, only the math collection gets copied and none of the other collections. Any thoughts?

Comment: None whatever. You haven't given us anything to look at.  Are we supposed to guess?

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely to be a synchronicity issue caused by calling `copyMathDatabase()` and `copyEnglishDatabase()`, which are both asynchronous, in sequence, try changing that block of your code to the following:

```
db.collection(this.state.email).doc("UserProfile").set(data).then(() =>{
    this.copyMathDatabase().then(() => {
        this.copyEnglishDatabase();
    });
});
```

This way your are forcing your code to be executed in the proper order and mitigating errors, and this should fix the issue you are facing.

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't work. Any idea why?